# Haskell: function composition has just damaged my brain

Tags: haskell

If

```
*Main> :t concatMap
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
```

and

```
*Main> :t replicate
replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]
```

then how does that work

```
*Main> :t concatMap . replicate
concatMap . replicate :: Int -> [b] -> [b]
```

given:

```
*Main> :t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

?

I mean, my understanding of function composition is that `replicate` should return whatever `concatMap` expects as arguments in order for `(.)` to work. But it does not LOOK to be the case. So what is the catch?

Comment: Are you asking why `a -> [a]` matches `a -> [b]`?

Comment: @sepp2k nope, the `a`s and `b`s part is pretty clear (I think)

Comment: +1 for epic question title. Brain damage is definitely a common consequence of advanced functional programming. ;-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It might help you to see what's going on if you add parentheses to the signatures and then line them up:

```
replicate :: Int -> (a -> [a])
concatMap ::        (a -> [b]) -> ([a] -> [b])
```

Now it should be fairly obvious that the output of `replicate` fits the input of `concatMap` if we unify `b` and `a`, in which case the output type of the composition is `[b] -> [b]`.

Answer (score 9):

The difficulty probably comes from confusing type variables and how
you reason about type unification.  The trick is to consider, as
others have said, that (->) is right-associative, meaning you can
line things up like this (making new type variables for each
signature to avoid confusion):

```
(.)       :: (b         ->  c         ) -> (a    -> b        )  -> a -> c
concatMap :: (q -> [r]) -> ([q] -> [r])
replicate ::                               (Int  -> (s -> [s])
```

This essentially gives us some constraints we need to resolve.
Let's say that "a ~ b" means "a is the same type as b" or
equivalently "a can be substituted with b."

From just the above, we can infer the following facts:

```
a ~ Int
b ~ (q -> [r]) ~ (s -> [s])
c ~ ([q] -> [r])
```

But the two equivalences for b tell us that

```
(q -> [r]) ~ (s -> [s])
```

which entails that

```
q ~ s and [r] ~ [s]
```

So then we rewrite c as:

```
c ~ ([q] -> [r]) ==> ([s] -> [s]))
```

Plugging the substitutions for a and c back into the original
type of (.) with the two functions applied yields

```
a -> c ~ Int -> ([s] -> [s])
```

which of course is now in the form that ghci reports: `Int -> [b] -> [b]`.